# Possible Concurrency Issue .NET XmlSerializer?

Tags: .net, soap, concurrency, xmlserializer

We have an application where a .NET client is consuming Java web services and we are experiencing, what appears to be, a very nasty concurrency issue. I have placed a ServletFilter on the Java side to log the incoming http soap message. And 99.9% of those requests are formatted correctly, however, every once a while the soap message sent from the .NET side has a malformed "xmlns" declaration in an IN/OUT parameter that is passed in the soap header.

The element "stateId" looks like this:

```
<soap:Header>
<stateId xmlns="http://webservice.lassen.landacorp.com <http://webservice.lassen.landacorp.com/> ">
.
.
.
</stateId></soap:Header>
```

The correctly formatted soap messages look like this:

```
<soap:Header>
<stateId xmlns="http://webservice.lassen.landacorp.com">
.
.
.
</stateId></soap:Header>
```

The generated .NET code for this type looks like the following:

```
namespace landacorp.common.datatypes {
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("stateId", Namespace = "http://webservice.lassen.landacorp.com", IsNullable = true)]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://xml.business.lib.landacorp.com")]
    [GeneratedCode("LandaWsdl", "1.0.0.0")]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    public class StateIdentifier : SoapHeader {
```

This is what the generated web service class looks like for the method in question:

```
[WebServiceBinding(Name = "RunUserDefinedWindowBinding", Namespace = "http://runuserdefinedwindow.webservice.lassen.landacorp.com/")]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[GeneratedCode("LandaWsdl", "1.0.0.0")]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public class RunUserDefinedWindowService : SoapHttpClientProtocol {
    public RunUserDefinedWindowService();

    public StateIdentifier stateId { get; set; }
.
.
.
    [SoapHeader("stateId", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
    [SoapDocumentMethod("", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public retrieveRecordResponse retrieveRecord(retrieveRecord retrieveRecord1);
```

I am currently looking at places where the stateId property may be set/referenced unsafely in a threaded environment.

Comment: Probably not the XmlSerializer but application code that's misusing it. Post it.

Comment: Why would this be a concurrency issue? Second, are you using "Add Service Reference", or "Add Web Reference"?

Comment: It's a concurrency issue because the same exact code path generates the correct soap message 99.9% of time. This error manifests when we attempt a 750 users load test and typically is reproduced about 40 minutes into that load test. This issue DOES not occur if we attempt the same script (run by the load test) manually. This error does not always happen during the load test either.

Comment: We are not using "Add Service Reference" or "Add Web Reference". We run the wsdl.exe command line (as part of our integration build) to generate all of the web service artifacts.